# How do I make this mod_rewrite scheme work with PHP as CGI/FCGI?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Here's the contents of .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"

# Disallow direct access to PHP files.
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [F,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?<!common/dispatch\.php/)(.*)?$ common/dispatch.php/$1 [NS,L]
```

Essentially I have all my pages (PHP files) arranged as they would be for direct access without `mod_rewrite` but I also have `dispatch.php` in a directory called `common`, through to which I want all requests to be directed so that I can do some processing before the page script is executed.

It's basically the same idea as used by most frameworks, except I want the page hierarchy to be at the top level and the dispatch script to be kept out of the way with some other bits and pieces in its own subdirectory.

This script works fine on my development machine (which is running PHP as `mod_php`), but on the production machine it produces an error saying "No input file specified." if running under FCGI. Under normal CGI it works for the most part but if, for example, I go to `/foo/bar` (with trailing slash missing) and `/foo/bar` is a directory in the docroot, it sends me to `/foo/bar/?/foo/bar`. The rest of the script works fine but I don't really want my URIs getting mangled like this, and ideally I'd like to be able to use FCGI as well.

A potential fix for the problem with FCGI seems to be to put the matched `$1` in the query string (i.e. after a `?`), but this causes all sorts of other odd behaviour that I haven't been able to fix. Is there a straightforward way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier just to use the `auto_prepend_file` directive in php?